# How to rearrange set date in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

This is my code

```
e1 = DateEntry(frameLabDate, textvariable=cVarChange, date_pattern='dd/mm/yyyy')
e1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=8)
```

I'm calling the date value inside a function

```
def fun():
    a=e1.get()
    Date = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

So here my input is like `22/10/2020`.
My desired output is `2020/10/22`

After executing the above code I get the following error.

```
ValueError: time data '2020-10-22' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DateEntry` is not a standard tkinter widget. What other module are you using?

Comment: The date in the error does not match with `date_pattern`.

Comment: @martineau It should be `tkcalender` module.

Comment: Use `a=e1.selection_get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
from datetime import datetime

def fun(a):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_str = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%Y/%m/%d')
    return date_str

fun("22/10/2020")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get_date()` instead of `get()` and use `strftime()` to convert the date to your desired format:

```py
def fun():
    a = e1.get_date() # return datetime.date object
    print(a.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')) # convert to desired format
```

Comment: Didn't worked as receiving data is in string format. I might not have done properly but answer from Harsha Biyani worked for me

Comment: `e1.get_date()` returns a `datetime.date` object, not string.  May be you need to change `print(a.strftime(...))` to `return a.strftime(...)`.

Comment: Problem with `get_date()` is its not taking string as input. I was receiving input in string format for whatsoever reason. So I had to first convert it to date by using `datetime.strptime` and then `datetime.strftime` to reformat it. I performed the following code `e1="22/10/2020"
b=e1.get_date()
print(b)`. It displays ` 'str' object has no attribute 'get_date' `